# Exported dashboard with Kibana API cannot be imported manually in Kibana UI

Tags: python, import, export, kibana, dashboard

I can get my exported dashboard using this code. The API is from the Kibana documentation :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/dashboard-api-export.html

```
tmpdir = '/tmp/kibana/dashboards/'

if not os.path.exists(tmpdir):
    os.makedirs(tmpdir)

dashboard = requests.get('http://localhost:5601/api/kibana/dashboards/export?dashboard=d83837a0-7c21-11eb-9dad-4b1b4ebf9d55')

json_dashboard = dashboard.json()

dashboards_exported = []
dashboards_exported.append(json_dashboard)

with open(tmpdir+'Dash'+'.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(dashboards_exported, outfile, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

The exported dashboard json file is the following :
https://pastebin.com/YZTKJFn3

However, when I want to import it manually to Kibana UI, it says "No objects imported".

When I export the dashboard manually from Kibana UI, I get the following NDJSON file : https://pastebin.com/nuRFKjPx

You can notice that the two files are slightly different and don't have the same format (JSON through API and NDJSON manually exported).
Therefore, I am not able to import manually the API generated JSON file. Do you have any idea of why Kibana does not find any object when I import the first JSON file ?

Comment: What version of Kibana / ES are you running? In earlier versions, there were small-but-significant formatting differences between the formats used in the saved_objects API and the GUI

Comment: I am using the 7.10.1 version for Kibana and ES

Answer (score 1):

Little late but I think you should import ndjson aswell.
curl way:

```
curl -X POST "{{ host_ip }}:{{ kibana_port }}/api/saved_objects/_import" -H "kbn-xsrf: true" --form file=@/tmp/kibana_stored_objects.ndjson
```